# Open PDF to a certain page?

Tags: command-line, batch-file, command-line-arguments, adobe-acrobat

I need a batch file command to open a pdf with the Acrobat Reader on a certain page.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" <PageNumber> <DocumentName>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [htype](http://htipe.wordpress.com/2010/10/20/adobe-acrobat-command-line-options/):

Syntax:

```
AcroRd32.exe /A "page=page_number" filename.pdf
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. Does anyone know what exactly the `/A` switch is? Even the adobe documentation does not say it, it only tells you to use it. What does the **A** stand for?